# What's the difference between setContentIntent and setFullScreenIntent in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

It seems like both involve showing a notification and then the user can touch the notification to launch your activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

> Every notification should respond to a tap, usually to open an
> activity in your app that corresponds to the notification. To do so,
> you must specify a content intent defined with a PendingIntent object
> and pass it to setContentIntent().

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive

> Use a full-screen intent only for the highest-priority alerts
> where you have an associated activity that you would like to launch after the user
> interacts with the notification.

So it seems like in both situations a notification shows that the user must interact with and then your activity is launched.

Comment: `setFullScreenIntent()`, in some circumstances, starts the activity directly, without requiring that interaction... at least on older devices. To be honest, I forget if they just subsumed that into the heads-up style on newer devices or not.

Comment: The issue I had with my device (which is newest OS) is that it didn't launch the activity straight away. It showed notification then I needed to tap. Maybe you are right that it only works on older device.

Comment: The primary scenario for where the activity would launch immediately was if the device's screen were off. Basically, at that point, the OS knows that it cannot be interrupting the user.